# Haskell - Give Type Declaration of Function

Tags: function, haskell, types, functional-programming

I am revising for a test that I have coming up on Haskell and one of the questions is:

> (b) Give type declarations to complete the following (possibly incomplete) function definitions:
>
> ii. `unzOp ((x,y):zs) = ((x+1):(fst(unzOp zs)),(y+2.5):(snd(unzOp zs)))`

Can somebody help me answer this question please? If you could breakdown on why the answer is what it is, then that would be much appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: How far did you get? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to identify the "shape" of data. You can do it by looking for constructors.
Here you have `(:)`, constructor for list and `(,)`, constructor for tuple.
You can deduce that the type has the shape

```
unzOp :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])
```

Then you can look for more constrains on `a` and `b`.
Because of `x+1`, you have to assume `x` is a number.
Because of `y+2.5`, you have to assume `y` is a number too, but fractional.

So,

```
unzOp :: (Num a, Fractional b) => [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])
```

To be honest the numeric types are not the easiest thing in Haskell.
You can ask for the type of an expression using `:t` in ghci.

```
:t (\x -> x + 1)
(\x -> x + 1) :: Num a => a -> a
```

By the way, what happens if you pass an empty list to `unzOp` ?

Or in other words, `unzOp` is defined recursively, but what is the base case ?